# Use greater than and less than symbol in HTML React/JSX:

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native

If we use > or < we get an error in react js

```
<div> > greater than ,< Less than </div>
```

Comment: The least you can do is use the backtick operator to bind anything static with dynamic.
Something like 
<div> ` > greater than ,< Less than` </div>.
For dynamic replacement in backtick
<div> `> greater than ,< Less than ${SomethingDynamic/variables }` </div>
This is something that very basic for the ES6 standards.

Answer (score 17):

You should replace:

`<` by `&lt;`

`>` by `&gt;`

Comment: @Trong Nguyen Cong
NO it doesn't work in react js

Comment: @Dev, Of course it works in React, it's standard HTML. See for yourself [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-gareth-994pf).

Answer (score 6):

We can not use the less than or greater than sign directly

Solution:

`<div>{"<"} Less than, {">"} greater than </div>`